# Joint density of two exponential random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution

For independent random variables X ∼ Exp(1) and Y ∼ Exp(2), find the density of (Z, W) = (X-2Y, X).

My approach:

Since for any exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$ the function is
$f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$

$f_X(x) =  e^{-x}$

$f_Y(y) = 2e^{-2y}$

Therefore the joint density function is: 
$$ f_{X, Y}(x, y) =f_X(x) f_Y(y) = \begin{cases} 2e^{-x-2y} \ & \mbox{ if } x \geq 0, y \geq 0;  \\ 0 \ & \mbox{ elsewhere}. \end{cases} $$

However I don't know how to use this to calculate $f_{Z, W}$

Comment: Don't you know any theorems that allow you to transform random vectors?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $g:(x,y) \mapsto (x-2y,x)$ is a differentiable and invertible function between $(0,\infty)\times (0,\infty)$ and $R=\{(z,w) | z< w \text{ and } w>0\}$, so first of all we get that the support for $(Z,W)=(X-2Y,X)$ must be $R$.

The transformation theorem for probability densities states that:

$$f_{Z,W}(z,w) = f_{X,Y}(g^{-1}(z,w)) |det(\frac{dg^{-1}}{d(z,w)}(z,w))|,$$
where $\frac{dg^{-1}}{d(z,w)}(z,w)$ is the jacobian of $g^{-1}$.

(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Vector_to_vector)

We first compute $g^{-1}(z,w)= (w,\frac{w-z}{2})$ and the jacobian
$$ \frac{dg^{-1}}{d(z,w)}(z,w) = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -\frac12 & \frac12 \end{pmatrix},$$
which has determinant $\frac12$ for all $z,w$. We now plugin, and get
$$ f_{Z,W}(z,w) = \frac12 f_{X,Y} ((w,\frac{w-z}{2})) = e^{-w}e^{-2\frac{w-z}{2}}=e^{z-2w}.$$
for all $(z,w) \in \{(z,w) | z< w \text{ and } w>0\}$. Just to verify, that this is in fact a valid density we compute 
$$ \int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^w e^{z-2w} dzdw = 1$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that while $X$ and $Y$ are nonnegative, $X-2Y$ may take negative values. So we need to treat these cases separately. For $t<0$, we have
\begin{align}
F_Z(t) &= \mathbb P(Z\leqslant t)\\
&= \mathbb P(2Y\geqslant X-t)\\
&= \int_0^\infty\int_{x-t}^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\frac\mu 2 e^{-\frac\mu 2y}\ \mathsf dy\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \frac{2 \lambda  e^{\frac{\mu  t}{2}}}{2 \lambda +\mu }.
\end{align}
For $t>0$, we have
\begin{align}
F_Z(t) &= \mathbb P(Z\leqslant t)\\
&= 1 - \mathbb P(2Y\geqslant X-t)\\
&= \int_t^\infty \int_0^{x-t} \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\frac\mu 2 e^{-\frac\mu 2y}\ \mathsf dy\ \mathsf dx\\
&= 1-\frac{\mu  e^{-\lambda  t}}{2 \lambda +\mu }.
\end{align}
Differentiating yields the density of $Z$:
$$
f_Z(t) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\lambda  \mu  e^{\frac{\mu  t}{2}}}{2 \lambda +\mu },& t<0\\
\frac{\lambda  \mu  e^{-\lambda  t}}{2 \lambda +\mu },& t>0
\end{cases}.
$$

Answer (score -3):

If I'm not wrong, you've formed the joint density function under the assumption that the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are *independent*.

In the formula for $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, let us put $X-2Y$ in place of $X$, $X$ in place of $Y$, and let us also put $x-2y$ in place of $x$ and $x$ in place of $y$ to obtain
$$ f_{Z, W}(z, w) = 2e^{- (x-2y) - x } = 2 e^{2y-2x} $$
if $x-2y \geq 0$ and $x\geq 0$, that is, if $x \geq \max(2y, 0)$, and $0$ otherwise.

However, I'm not completely sure if my solution is correct.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, yes X and Y are independent but I think that independence of X and Y doesn't imply independence of X-2Y and X

Comment: No of course not. $X, X-2Y$ are not independent because intuitively $X-2Y$ depends on $X$.